# How to fix the "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"

Tags: python, typeerror

We were given a fairly simple flowchart to convert into Python, asking us for employee name, hourly rate, hours worked, deduction, gross pay, and net pay. Afterwards, we have to then print the employee's name along with their netpay. The problem I encountered is that this error, "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str" always appears.

```
`employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
employee_name = str(employee_name)
hourly_rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
deduction = float(input("Enter amount of deduction: "))

net_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate
net_pay = str(net_pay)
gross_pay = net_pay - deduction

print(employee_name + " has a net pay of " + str(net_pay))`
```

I've been told that I just have to net_pay to str, but I don't exactly know what that means. Thank you in advance for anyone willing to assist me in this matter. As my username says, I'm a college freshman and we were given this assignment without being taught anything about solving Python problems.

Comment: `str` is a string i.e. text while `float` is for numbers. You can do math only with numbers. So you need to be aware what kind of variable you have and what you do with it.

Comment: Not strictly a code problem, but "gross" and "net" usually have the opposite meaning to how they are used here. "Gross" is the pay before deductions, and "net" is gross minus deduction.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work and probably do what you want:

```py
employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
hourly_rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
deduction = float(input("Enter amount of deduction: "))

net_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate
gross_pay = net_pay - deduction

print(employee_name + " has a net pay of " + str(net_pay))
```

I removed the line where `employee_name` is converted to `str`. It didn't hurt but was just superfluous and as it is already a `str`.

The problem was the other line I removed where you converted `net_pay` to `str` but did computations on it later when you computed `gross_pay`.

This way, `net_pay` is converted to `str` only when printing it.

Note that `gross_pay` is never used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Before concatenating the strings, you must convert the net pay variable to a string,
Like so:

```
employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
employee_name = str(employee_name)
hourly_rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
deduction = float(input("Enter amount of deduction: "))

net_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate
gross_pay = net_pay - deduction

print(employee_name + " has a net pay of " + str(net_pay))
```

We use str() to convert net pay to a string before concatenating it with the other strings.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made is that you wanted to calculate with a string, but you can't because python sees a string as text and not as numbers. So you have to calculate with a float, he sees this as numbers.

I hope this explanation helped you a bit.

Have a nice day.

```
employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
employee_name = str(employee_name)
hourly_rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
deduction = float(input("Enter amount of deduction: "))

#here you create 2 net_pay's, one is a string (string = text so to print), the other is a float (float = number so you can calculate with)
net_payFloat = hours_worked * hourly_rate
net_payString = str(net_payFloat)
gross_pay = net_payFloat - deduction

#here you don't need to make a string of net_pay because, you already have one named net_payString
print(employee_name + " has a net pay of " + net_payString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
employee_name = str(employee_name)
hourly_rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
deduction = float(input("Enter amount of deduction: "))

net_pay = hours_worked * hourly_rate
#net_pay = str(net_pay) <------- remove this line
gross_pay = net_pay - deduction

print(employee_name + " has a net pay of " + str(net_pay))`
```

You are converting `net_pay` variable to string and applying math operation on that string. That's why you getting the error. You don't need that line, you can convert it only when you are printing.